# Solr 5.1: Problems with search queries containing underscores

Tags: solr, solr5

I've indexed an internal website using Solr 5.1 and the new managed schema.  I've indexed the page title, url, and body using "text_en" and "text_en_splitting".  I get pretty much the behavior I want except when the query string contains underscores.

My use case is the following:  Suppose we have 3 terms, "first", "second" and "third", and that "second" does not exist in the index but "first" and "third" do.  When the search term is "first second third", I get the behavior I want (i.e. pages with "first" and "third" are returned).

However, when the search term is "first_second_third", I get 0 results, but I would expect to get something since "first" and "third" exist in the index.

I'm using edismax search with qf=url_txt_en title_txt_en title_txt_en_split text_txt_en_split

Can someone suggest a way to tweak my config to get what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the definition for `text_en_splitting` that comes with the Solr examples?

If so, the issue is that this type uses `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory`, which creates tokens separated by splitting on whitespace. It will ignore underscores.

Instead, it sounds like you need to tokenize on both whitespace and underscores. So try replacing that with [PatternTokenizerFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternTokenizerFactory), like so:

```
<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="_\s*" />
```

Don't forget to change this in both the index and query analyzer blocks.

Comment: The text_en_splitting definition uses the WordDelimiterFilterFactory, which according to the docs should be splitting on non alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: @Stephan It's true that the fieldType also includes WordDelimiterFilterFactory, which is often used to complement a whitespace tokenizer. However, I don't see any options for WordDelimiterFilterFactory that can split words on underscores. That's why I think you need to change the tokenizer. If you only want to update the filters, you could try adding [PatternReplaceFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory) just before the WordDelimiterFilterFactory to replace underscores with spaces, although that is essentially a tokenizer.

Comment: From the docs, it says it should split on "non alpha-numeric" characters, so it should work on underscore by default; they give as an example "Wi-Fi", which gets split into "Wi" and "Fi".  Further, the output of the analyzer shows that the WDF splits "first_second_third" into "first", "second" and "third"; which is what I'm after.  I just don't know why my queries come up empty.

Comment: In the docs here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory it says that tokenization can be customized by using a "types" file.  Maybe the answer lies there.

Comment: @Stephan If you don't know why something is as it seems to be - use the analysis page under the Solr Admin with the given field type selected. That allows you to enter the indexed and the queried value, and you can see how both parts are being tokenized and processed for each step.

Comment: Yes, I did.  The analysis page shows that "first_second_third" is split into "first", "second" and "third" as well as "firstsecondthird" both the index and query fields.  That's why I don't understand why my query returns 0 matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below field type which used WordDelimiterFilterFactory. It Splits words into subwords and performs optional transformations on subword groups.

By default, words are split into subwords with the following rules:

1.split on intra-word delimiters (all non alpha-numeric characters).
   "Wi-Fi" -> "Wi", "Fi"

2.split on case transitions (can be turned off - see splitOnCaseChange parameter)
   "PowerShot" -> "Power", "Shot"

3.split on letter-number transitions (can be turned off - see splitOnNumerics parameter)
   "SD500" -> "SD", "500"

```
<fieldtype name="subword" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

Comment: The pipeline is already using WordDelimiterFilterFactory; the issue I have is understanding why it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: add and try with <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=" " replace="all"/>....

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert _ with any non-alphanumeric character that your Tokenizer tokenize on. In following case I converted it to hyphen '-' which is a valid delimiter for  StandardTokenizerFactory

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" 
                    pattern="_" 
                    replacement="-"/>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
```