# solR query not detecting underscore in Cassandra-Datastax

Tags: solr, datastax

I have the following solR query:

```
select * from testkspc.test_tbl_nm where solr_query = '{"q":"ptcde:\"RP_INC\""}';
```

This doesn't return any result although the respective data is available in DB for ptcde=RP_INC.

On the other hand, queries where "underscores" are absent are fetching expected  results.
E.g.:

```
select * from testkspc.test_tbl_nm where solr_query = '{"q":"ptcde:\"test2805\""}';
```

I have tried to escape it as well, but that doesn't return any result either:

```
select * from testkspc.test_tbl_nm where solr_query = '{"q":"ptcde:\"RP\\_INC\""}';
```

Comment: [solr-5-1-problems-with-search-queries-containing-underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378599/solr-5-1-problems-with-search-queries-containing-underscores) This answer maybe works for you.

Comment: @Arty - unfortunately it's not the use-case i am looking for.

Comment: This question does not provide additional information such as the version of the Cassandra (e.g. OSS C* / DataStax Enterprise (DSE) / etc.), version of Solr, table schema and data types, the solr index configs, any log related items, etc. to be able to see what's going on.